# Back Button Functionality Kivy with Screen Cache

Tags: android, kivy

I have a bunch of screens in my app and I would like the back button to work universally to go back to a previous screen. I have been trying to implement a stack and pop the previous screen but for some reason the Window binding method solution that I found does not work completely.

```
class RegisterScreen(Screen):
    screenlist = ListProperty([])
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # Setting it up to listen for keyboard events
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.onBackBtn)
    def onBackBtn(self, window, key, *args):
       """ To be called whenever user presses Back/Esc Key """
        # If user presses Back/Esc Key
        if key == 27:
            print(self.screenlist)
            self.manager.current = self.screenlist[len(screenlist)]
            return True
```

The problem with this code is the __init__ override method. I think binding the on_keyboard function to the Window is making *all* back button presses use the onBackBtn method. How can I solve this?

TLDR: How do I allow the back button to go back on a stack of previous screens?

I am mainly using KV Language but the back button implementation is easier to do in Python I think...

Comment: Clarification: I realize that all back button presses use the onBackBtn method but I'm not sure how to make it go back to previous screens

Answer (score 0):

i dont think overiding the  **init** causes this problem and ofcourse all the back presses will call the onBackBtn function because it is referring to the key which is 27 which actually means the back button..check this out https://pastebin.com/3CTv6GQV

Comment: But should I have the onBackBtn function inside the screen widget or inside the app widget?